# Data binding issues

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have started using the Entity Framework quite recently and think it is very good but I am a bit confused over a couple of things.

I'm writing a winforms-application where you are presented a list of persons in a list and if you click a particular person more information about that person appears in textboxes. Nothing fancy so far, but you are supposed to be able to edit the data about the person so data binding is nice here.

It works just fine but I am bit confused about what is the correct way to do it. First I did like this:

```
var query = _context.Person.Where(c => c.Id == chosenId);
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Then I read a bit and tried:

```
var local = _context.Person.Local;  
IEnumerable<Customer> enumerable = local.Where(c => c.Id == chosenId);
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = enumerable.ToList();
```

This one seems to work fine as well.

Then I saw that someone suggested something like:

```
_context.Person.Load();
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Person.Local.ToBindingList();
```

I am a bit confused right now on what approach is the correct one and what is the difference between these three? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the first and second example you have there is one is deferred and one is not. The third one is a little different as it creates a two way binding between your database and control datasource, effectively making the datacontext track changes to the list for you (add, & deletes).

In all your examples, so long as you keep you datacontext open changes to the objects themselves would be tracked.

As far as which way is correct, that depends on your application.  Pick the approach that works best for you based on what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 2):

## Depends on What You Want to do

I honestly never liked getting this answer because it seems to be the answer to everything but in this case it is really the only answer I can give

### What the Local Property Does

Local gives you a reference to the current elements being tracked by the data context that hasn't been marked by delete, essentially you are asking for the current object that have already been loaded into memory by the context, you can read more about it here

[DbSet(TEntity).Local Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.103).aspx)

### What The Load Method Does

The Load method eagerly loads the targeted context, you can read more about it here.

[DbExtensions.Load Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbextensions.load(v=vs.103).aspx)

### What ToBindingList Does

Basically this is creating a two way binding between whatever entity you have created and the UI when you use a collection created using this method. That is that any changes in the UI should be automatically reflected in the related entities within this collection. You can read more about it using the following links

[BindingList(T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx)
 [DbExtensions.ToBindingList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696575(v=vs.103).aspx)

### What Each Of Your Examples Do

#### First Example

```
var query = _context.Person.Where(c => c.Id == chosenId);
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Under the covers the following is going on

1. Creating a Query to be processed by the server with your linq expression
2. Getting the content from the database and creating a list around it

Here you are grabbing any of the people with Id of chosen Id from the database and then loading them into your application and creating a list

#### Second Example

```
var local = _context.Person.Local;  
IEnumerable<Customer> enumerable = local.Where(c => c.Id == chosenId);
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = enumerable.ToList();
```

Under the covers the following is going on

1. Getting all of the currently tracked objects by the context object that have been hit by a query but have not been marked as deleted
2. getting all of the elements in local memory that have the Id chosen Id

Here you are grabbing any people that have already been loaded into the context  **this is not going to get all of your persisted data items**, you must have hit them in other queries

#### Third Example

```
_context.Person.Load();
this.personBindingSource.DataSource = _context.Person.Local.ToBindingList();
```

Under the covers the following is going on

1. You are loading **all of the people into local memory**
2. You create binding list (allows two way data binding between the objects and the UI)
3. You bind the list to the UI element personBindingSource

Unless you want to load all of the items into memory this is probably not what you want to do, if the dataset ever grows large enough it will slow your program down and could possibly cause it to not work correctly (unlikely with case of person in most scenarios but is possible)

### When You Should Use Them

#### First

When you want to just get the data that matches your query into local memory and don't need a link between UI and the entities

#### Second

When you have already run a query in the context and need to use it someplace else but don't need to rerun the query since it is currently in memory

#### Third

When you want to load all of the elements of an entity set into memory and create a two way databinding between them and a control

Comment: Wow! Great answer, thanks for that! One thing thou. When I use the 'First' one and change a value in the UI and then uses context.SaveChanges(), that change is actually persisted in the database. From what I understood from the part under "When you should use them" -> "First" there should not be any link available, but there must be data binding active in that case too. Or did I misunderstood what you meant?

Comment: In general you cannot depend on the changes being persisted back, in some context they might but in others they may not. I don't think it is a requirement for the list object to update changes from data binding, BindList does have that as part of its definition.